# PHP Code IF POST

Tags: php

I have a "text_box" as the submit POST and what I want it to do is, when the "text_box" is posted with the username "john" it redirects them to a certain site here's my code

```
<?php


if(isset($_POST['text_box']))
{


    $username = $_POST['text_box'];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$text = $_POST['text_box'];

if (isset($text) && $text == "john") {
    header("Location: www.example.com");
}
```

You should not perform any other job before header part.